# android Having an issue with resource subfolders

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-resource-qualifiers

I have used resource subfolders on multiple projects; but I am now having some difficulties.  There are two methods for adding subfolders; however they both rely on the same thing.  Adding the folders to your sourceSets resources.  Here is that block in my gradle file

```
 getByName("main") {
            res { 
                srcDirs("src/main/res/layouts/sample")
                srcDirs("src/main/res/drawables/sample")
                srcDirs("src/main/res")
            }
        }
```

Here are the folder structures.  Notice I am using the inner nested layout folder.

After this block when I log out the resources.  They are there

```
sourceSets main res dirs: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet@2d0da729, type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.artifact.SourceArtifactTyp
e$ANDROID_RESOURCES@4f90eaf9, source=[src/main/res, src/main/res/drawable/test, src/main/res/layouts/sample, src/main/res/drawables/sample, src/main/res]
```

What can I do to debug this issue?  Are there gradle tasks or properties or logging techniques that could help me?

[image]